# Creating shapefile in standalone script using PyQGIS?

Tags: shapefile, pyqgis

I'm trying to write a standalone script that writes a shapefile (using QGIS 3.0.2). I've tried something like :

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from qgis.utils import QGis


QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.initQgis()

fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField("ID_HYD", QVariant.Int))
fields.append(QgsField("SBD_KM2", QVariant.Double))


writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("/home/sylvain/test.shp",
                             "CP1250",
                             fields,
                             QGis.WKBPoint,
                             None,
                             "ESRI Shapefile")

qgs.exitQgis()
```

The issue is as follow :

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 /home/sylvain/test.py
Must construct a QGuiApplication first.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there a way to write a shapefile on drive without constructing a GUIApplication ?

If not, how should I do do create such an item ?

Comment: Did my advice provide any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting the error in line 3 `from qgis.utils import QGis`. 
In QGIS 3, geometry types is specified by `QgsWkbTypes` enum in `core` library. Thus, remove `from qgis.utils import QGis`

Use script in the following way. Notice highlighted lines with `####`.

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
# from qgis.utils import QGis  # REMOVE THIS LINE ####

QgsApplication.setPrefixPath("/usr/bin/qgis", True)
qgs = QgsApplication([], False)

qgs.initQgis()

fields = QgsFields()
fields.append(QgsField("ID_HYD", QVariant.Int))
fields.append(QgsField("SBD_KM2", QVariant.Double))


writer = QgsVectorFileWriter("/home/sylvain/test.shp",
                             "CP1250",
                             fields,
                             QgsWkbTypes.Point, #### instead of QGis.WKBPoint
                             QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(), #### instead of None
                             "ESRI Shapefile")

qgs.exitQgis()
```

Answer (score 4):

One of the easiest python libraries to read/write shapefiles is [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#writing-shapefiles).
You can install it with pip:

`pip install pyshp`

After you can import the library and create your shapefile:

```
import shapefile

out_file = 'test.shp'

# Set up a shapefile writer
writer = shapefile.Writer(shapeType=shapefile.POINT)
# Create empty fields
writer.field("ID_HYD", "N")  # integer field - see pyshp docs
writer.field("SBD_KM2", "F")  # float field - see pyshp docs

# Save shapefile
writer.save(out_file)
```

These links may help you to get started:

1. [Official pyshp docs](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp#overview)
2. [Another library to create shapefiles with python - ogr](http://www.digital-geography.com/create-and-edit-shapefiles-with-python-only/)

Answer (score 2):

Just use FIONA a python wrapper for OGR and allows you to build and convert any data. Or just OGR2OGR